# What is the default Soap Version for SoapServer in PHP?

Tags: php, soap

I have a question from a client, asking if our Soap server is expecting Soap v1.1 or v1.2.

The only configuration in the SoapServer constructor is  the WSDL

`$server = new SoapServer(__CONFIG_PATH_WSDL_DISK);`

If no option for 'soap_version' is specified in the the [SoapServer constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapserver.soapserver.php) , what is the default version, or will it handle both?

Drew J. Sonne.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the second half of your question, yes, it supports both:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.soap.php

Answer (score 3):

> A simple way is to check for
>   Content-Type header during the
>   transaction.
>
> SOAP 1.1 uses text/xml SOAP 1.2 uses
>   application/soap

from [this link](http://osdir.com/ml/python.general.bangpypers/2008-03/msg00061.html)

Comment: I agree, checking the outgoing headers is probably your best bet if you want to see which version PHP is using.